# How can I download a server file in angular2

Tags: angular

I have the path of image file. I want that when users click the download button, the file should be downloaded to their computers or devices.

```
<button (click)="downloadfile()"></button>
```

When the button is clicked , the following component code should download the file to the user's device:

```
downloadfile(){
   const id = "c64eb0be068249333fd092957aa99190";
   this.storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(`audios/${id}`);
    this.storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
    const fileUrl = url;
   });
}
```

How can I use headers in angular2 to download the file , setting the file type and filename?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 provides donwload atribute to forces user to download a file
Click here to download
This will open a save as dialog in your browser.may be you can replace url in anchor ta with your response and click on it dynamically after your response from firebase